# What is the difference between future provider and future builder in flutter(dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

When should I use future builder or future provider. It seems to me they do almost same work.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is from [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72533331/14434426)

- FutureProvider: you can use this to retrieve a document from
  firestore and show a loading screen while waiting, but can't make
  changes to it afterwards, that will also show in the UI
- FutureBuilder: same as above but it can't provide data
  down the widget-tree